# Regex : Ass subtitles - Match the last \b tag value

Tags: regex

I want to match the numeric values of the **last** \b tag, or empty string if there's no number.

Here are the strings at left, and what I want to match at right :

```
\b                     Empty string
\b\b                   Empty string
\b1\b                  Empty string
\b\b1                  1
\b\b\i1                Empty string
\b1\blur0              1
\b2\b10anana           10
\b2\b1 0anana          1
\b2\bbanana10          Empty string
```

- B tags with numeric value should return an empty string
- In ass language the only tags starting with the b letters are \blur \bord and \be
- There can be spaces between \b and the number but *not* after the number, hence why `\b2\b1 0anana` should give "1"
- Obviously bbanana is not a real ass tag, but ass libraries consider tags starting by \b as the \b tag as long as it's not blur/bord/be.
- Also, important precision : the \b tag can be "\ b" or "\b " (with as many spaces as possible)
- I use a regex module that work like .NET (C#) regex in regex101

I'm currently stucked with this regex https://regex101.com/r/0TZeSn/1

```
(?<=\\\s*b\s*)\d+(?!(?=\\b))|(?<=\\b)(?!.*\\b).*?(?=\w|\\)
```

It's hard to come by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a match only without empty matches, you might use:

```
(?<=\\ *b *)(?!\S*\\b *(?!lur|ord|e))\d+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\\ *b *)` Positive lookbehind, assert `\b` with optional spaces in between to the left
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert not to the right

  - `\S*\\b *(?!lur|ord|e)` Match optional non whitespace chars followed by `\b` that is not directly followed by `lur` `ord` or `e`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdygdr/1).

To also get empty matches, you can match optional digits and assert not `lur` `ord` or `e` directly after the current position and also not directly after matching `\b`

```
(?<=\\ *b *)(?!lur|ord|e|\S*\\b *(?!lur|ord|e))\d*
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/18v2Js/1).

Comment: The second pattern is exactly what I wanted to do ! Thank you very much